# Unity 2D Ball Bounce

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello i am new to unity2d and trying to make a simple game.There is a ball on the middle of the screen and there are walls left and right.I want the ball to go top right and after it hits the wall i want it to go top left like zig zag movement.I used this code but it kept on going right all the time.Can you help me with this?

```
public class BallMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 movement1 = new Vector2(1f, 1f);
    private Vector2 movement2 = new Vector2(-1f, 1f);
    public float speed;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(movement1 * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Right Wall")
        {
            transform.Translate(movement2 * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because in update you move it to the right. You need the collision to toggle between right and left

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Well. Have a try and think before you have it handed to you

Comment: Okay thank you for your help i will try :)

Comment: If you use Physics and Rigidbody2D you don't want to move using `Transform` at all! Rather use `rigidbody.MovePosition` in `FixedUpdate` or simply set its `velocity` once

Comment: Okay i will try that thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
public class BallMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 movement = new Vector2(1f, 1f);
    public float speed;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(movement * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        var tag = collision.gameObject.tag;
        if(tag == "wall")
        {
            movement.x *= -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See. How much better you feel for working it out